# PongGame reinforcement learning with stable-baselines and pygame

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I'm trying write PongGame AI with pygame and stable-baselines. Environment is ready and working. For the agent, im using custom env documentation stable-baselines  (https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/custom_env.html)

But when i use check environment.py , error occuring which is

```
"assertion error: reset() method doesnt matching with observation space"
```

Game is working properly as i said but when i try make this with customEnv the error occuring which i wrote.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Goksel\anaconda3\envs\tensor37\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File "c:\users\goksel\desktop\checkenv.py", line 9, in 
check_env(env)

File "C:\Users\Goksel\anaconda3\envs\tensor37\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines\common\env_checker.py", line 214, in check_env
_check_returned_values(env, observation_space, action_space)

File "C:\Users\Goksel\anaconda3\envs\tensor37\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines\common\env_checker.py", line 99, in _check_returned_values
_check_obs(obs, observation_space, 'reset')

File "C:\Users\Goksel\anaconda3\envs\tensor37\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines\common\env_checker.py", line 89, in _check_obs
"method does not match the given observation space".format(method_name))

AssertionError: The observation returned by the `reset()` method does not match the given observation space

files and codes github link for those who want it:
https://github.com/RsGoksel/PongGame-AI.git

video resources which i used:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKnjGn8fF70&t=1493s

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBCU-tqLGfQ&t=3551s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bD6V3rcr_54&t=934s
```

```
import gym
from gym import spaces

import pygame
import random
import numpy as np

HEIGHT = 450
WIDTH = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (50,0,200)


def updatePaddle(action, paddleY):
    
    
    if action == 0:
        paddleY.rect.y -= 4
        
    if action == 1:
        return
       
    if action == 2:
        paddleY.rect.y += 4
    
      
    if paddleY.rect.y < 0:  
        paddleY.rect.y = 0
    
    if paddleY.rect.y > HEIGHT:
        paddleY.rect.y = HEIGHT
    
    return paddleY.rect.y


class PongEnv(gym.Env):
  
    metadata = {'render.modes': ['human']}
      
    
    class paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self,color):
           pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
           self.image = pygame.Surface([WIDTH/40,HEIGHT/4.5])
           self.image.fill(color)
           self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
           
    
    class ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.image = pygame.Surface([WIDTH/40,WIDTH/40])
            self.image.fill(red)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.Xspeed = 3
            self.Yspeed = 3
    
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(PongEnv, self).__init__()
        
        self.reward = 0
        self.done = False
        self.score = 0
        
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(3)
        
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=255,
                                            shape=(1,HEIGHT, WIDTH), dtype=np.float32)
    
    
        self.pedal1 = self.paddle(blue)
        self.pedal2 = self.paddle(blue)
        self.BALL = self.ball()
        
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.all_sprites.add(self.pedal1, self.pedal2, self.BALL)
        
        #paddle1 and paddle2(bot) location
        self.pedal1.rect.x = WIDTH/50 #25
        self.pedal1.rect.y = random.randint(0,HEIGHT/10)*10 #300
        
        self.pedal2.rect.x = 23*WIDTH/24 #575
        self.pedal2.rect.y =  random.randint(0,HEIGHT/10)*10
        
        
        #ball location. at the beginning of each round, the ball's destination flank changes
        self.BALL.rect.x = WIDTH/2
        self.BALL.rect.y = HEIGHT/4 + random.randint(0, int(3/4*HEIGHT))
        
        self.BALL.Xspeed = random.sample([-self.BALL.Xspeed,self.BALL.Xspeed],1)[0]
        self.BALL.Yspeed = random.sample([-self.BALL.Yspeed,self.BALL.Yspeed],1)[0]
        
        
    def step(self, action):
        
        
        self.BALL.rect.x += self.BALL.Xspeed
        self.BALL.rect.y += self.BALL.Yspeed 
        
        self.pedal2.rect.y = self.BALL.rect.y - (WIDTH/40)
        
        
        if action==0:
            #self.pedal1.rect.y -+= 4
            updatePaddle(0, self.pedal1)
            
        if action==2:
            updatePaddle(2, self.pedal1)
        
       
        #if ball hits pedal1, score for paddle because its is exactly what we want
        if self.pedal1.rect.colliderect(self.BALL.rect):
            self.BALL.Xspeed *= -1
            self.score += 5
            self.reward = self.score
            
            
        #collider with paddle2
        if self.pedal2.rect.colliderect(self.BALL.rect):
            self.BALL.Xspeed *= -1 
       
        #control for ball and boundries
        if self.BALL.rect.y > HEIGHT - (WIDTH/40) or self.BALL.rect.y < WIDTH/200: #435 or self.top.rect.y < 3
             self.BALL.Yspeed *= -1
             
             #its negative score for agent.
        if self.BALL.rect.x <= WIDTH/120:    #self.pedal1.rect.x yazılabilirdi fakat const değişken ile 
             self.score -= 10
             self.reward = self.score
             done = True
    
        self.observation = [self.pedal1.rect.x, self.pedal1.rect.y, self.BALL.rect.x, self.BALL.rect.y] 
        self.observation = np.array(self.observation)
        
        
        info = {}
        return self.observation, self.reward, self.done, info        
        
          
    def reset(self):
        self.done = False
        self.score = 0
        
        
        self.pedal1.rect.x = WIDTH/50 #25
        self.pedal1.rect.y = random.randint(0,HEIGHT/10)*10 #300
        
        
        self.pedal2.rect.x = 23*WIDTH/24 #575
        self.pedal2.rect.y =  random.randint(0,HEIGHT/10)*10
        
        
        self.BALL.rect.x = WIDTH/2
        self.BALL.rect.y = HEIGHT/4 + random.randint(0, int(3/4*HEIGHT))
        
        self.BALL.Xhiz = random.sample([-self.BALL.Xspeed,self.BALL.Xspeed],1)[0]
        self.BALL.Yhiz = random.sample([-self.BALL.Yspeed,self.BALL.Yspeed],1)[0]
        
        self.observation = [self.pedal1.rect.x, self.pedal1.rect.y, self.BALL.rect.x, self.BALL.rect.y] 
        self.observation = np.array(self.observation)
        
        return self.observation  # reward, done, info can't be included
       
            
        
    def render(self, mode='human'):
        
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.init()
           
    
        
        while True: 
            
            pygame.time.delay(10)
            
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.display.quit()
                    pygame.quit()
                
            pygame.display.update()
    
            self.ekran.fill(black)
            self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
            #self.step(0)
    
    def close (self):
        if self.screen is not None:
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
```

and other checkenv.py file:

```
from stable_baselines.common.env_checker import check_env
from Stable import PongEnv

env = PongEnv()

check_env(env)
```

```
error: AssertionError: The observation returned by the `reset()` method does not match the given observation space
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: compare `observation_space` in `__init__` with `self.observation` in `reset()` - as for me they not match. `observation_space` is a screen - array with size `HEIGHT, WIDTH` but `observation` has only 4 values - it should be array with the same size HEIGHT, WIDTH,  or you have to change `observation_space` and use array with size `1, 4`

Comment: Mightly observation space which is in __init__ is correct.  Than which form is true at reset method for observation space. in some of the videos i've been watched reset was same as mine. So how is its true way (reset method's observation space)?

Comment: if you saw it in some videos then you could add link in question (not in comments) so all people could see it.